# Keep system theme with stylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt

I try to make disappear the borders of a QTableView, with a stylesheet:

```
        self.tableau.setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid transparent")
```

But when I do that, I loose the system theme on my widget, especially for the scroll bar. I'm on Linux. Any idea why this is happening ? Do I have to add another css option ?

Comment: when you set the style sheet for a widget it will overide the default property of the widget. so you have to set the scroll bar's style to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Ok. But is there a way, like a css option, to keep the system style ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the original style of the `QTableView` you can use `setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame)` or `setLineWidth(0)`. `QTableView` ingerits those methods from `QFrame`. If you want to do it with stylesheet I think there is no way to keep the original OS theme.